# How to test first and last digit of a (text) number?

Tags: macros

Various fonts have some built-in fractions and/or the ability to construct fractions with the +frac font feature. They tend to look great, but are so small that they are hard to read.

So I'm trying to spin my own fraction macro, and find that I need to make kerning adjustments around the solidus. I can test the value of the entire numerator or denominator, but I really want to test just the last character of the numerator and the first character of the denominator.

How can I do this? What I have follows, but only works for single-digit numerators and denominators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}
%\newfontfamily\fracfigs{STIXTwoText-Medium}[% compensate weight for scaling
%  Numbers = {Proportional,Lining},
%  Scale   = 0.75]

% Actual kerns wrong for this font, but everyone will have it:
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\fracfigs{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale = 0.75]

\newcommand*\myFii{2}
\newcommand*\myFiv{4}
\newcommand*\myFvi{6}
\newcommand*\myFvii{7}
\newcommand*\myFix{9}
\newcommand*\myfrac[2]{%
  \def\myfractmpn{#1}% Really want just last char
  \def\myfractmpd{#2}% Really want just first char
  \raisebox{0.5ex}{{\fracfigs#1}}%
  \ifx\myfractmpn\myFii       \kern 0.1em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpn\myFvii \kern -0.05em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpn\myFix  \kern 0pt%
  \else                       \kern 0.05em%
  \fi\fi\fi%
  \textfractionsolidus%
  \ifx\myfractmpd\myFiv       \kern -0.05em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpd\myFvi  \kern 0pt%
  \else                       \kern 0.05em%
  \fi\fi%
  {\fracfigs#2}}

\begin{document}
\myfrac{1}{1}\quad \myfrac{11}{11}\par
\myfrac{2}{2}\quad \myfrac{22}{22}\par
\myfrac{3}{3}\quad \myfrac{33}{33}\par
\myfrac{4}{4}\quad \myfrac{44}{44}\par
\myfrac{5}{5}\quad \myfrac{55}{55}\par
\myfrac{6}{6}\quad \myfrac{66}{66}\par
\myfrac{7}{7}\quad \myfrac{77}{77}\par
\myfrac{8}{8}\quad \myfrac{88}{88}\par
\myfrac{9}{9}\quad \myfrac{99}{99}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just introduce expandable macros to grab the first or the last digit of the string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}
%\newfontfamily\fracfigs{STIXTwoText-Medium}[% compensate weight for scaling
%  Numbers = {Proportional,Lining},
%  Scale   = 0.75]

% Actual kerns wrong for this font, but everyone will have it:
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\fracfigs{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale = 0.75]
\def\getfirst#1#2\relax{#1}
\def\getlast#1#2\relax{\if\relax#2\relax#1\else\getlast#2\relax\fi}

\newcommand*\myFii{2}
\newcommand*\myFiv{4}
\newcommand*\myFvi{6}
\newcommand*\myFvii{7}
\newcommand*\myFix{9}
\newcommand*\myfrac[2]{%
  \edef\myfractmpn{\getlast#1\relax}% Really want just last char
  \edef\myfractmpd{\getfirst#2\relax}% Really want just first char
  \raisebox{0.5ex}{{\fracfigs#1}}%
  \ifx\myfractmpn\myFii       \kern 0.1em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpn\myFvii \kern -0.05em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpn\myFix  \kern 0pt%
  \else                       \kern 0.05em%
  \fi\fi\fi%
  \textfractionsolidus%
  \ifx\myfractmpd\myFiv       \kern -0.05em%
  \else\ifx\myfractmpd\myFvi  \kern 0pt%
  \else                       \kern 0.05em%
  \fi\fi%
  {\fracfigs#2}}

\begin{document}
\myfrac{1}{1}\quad \myfrac{11}{11}\par
\myfrac{2}{2}\quad \myfrac{22}{22}\par
\myfrac{3}{3}\quad \myfrac{33}{33}\par
\myfrac{4}{4}\quad \myfrac{44}{44}\par
\myfrac{5}{5}\quad \myfrac{55}{55}\par
\myfrac{6}{6}\quad \myfrac{66}{66}\par
\myfrac{7}{7}\quad \myfrac{77}{77}\par
\myfrac{8}{8}\quad \myfrac{88}{88}\par
\myfrac{9}{9}\quad \myfrac{99}{99}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.  BTW, you need another `edef` for \myfractmpn. I tried to edit your answer but was told by the system that edit must be longer than my 1-character change.

Comment: @dedded Yes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `expl3`; with `\tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 }` we extract the last item in the argument and with `\tl_item:nn { #2 } { 1 }` the first item.

It should be clear how to fill in the kerns for other digits. Note that in the second call, the `F` argument for “no match” is used to insert the default kern of 0.05em.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\newfontface{\fracfigs}{STIXTwoText-Medium}[% compensate weight for scaling
  Extension=.otf,
  Numbers = Proportional,
  Scale   = 0.75,
]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfrac}{mm}
 {
  \dedded_myfrac:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dedded_myfrac:nn
 {
  \raisebox{0.5ex}{\fracfigs #1}
  \str_case_e:nn { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {
    {2}{\kern 0.1em}
    {7}{\kern -0.05em}
    {9}{\kern 0.05em}
   }
  \textfractionsolidus
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } }
   {
    {4}{\kern 0.05em}
    {6}{}
   }
   {\kern 0.05em}
   {\fracfigs#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myfrac{1}{1}\quad \myfrac{11}{11}\par
\myfrac{2}{2}\quad \myfrac{22}{22}\par
\myfrac{3}{3}\quad \myfrac{33}{33}\par
\myfrac{4}{4}\quad \myfrac{44}{44}\par
\myfrac{5}{5}\quad \myfrac{55}{55}\par
\myfrac{6}{6}\quad \myfrac{66}{66}\par
\myfrac{7}{7}\quad \myfrac{77}{77}\par
\myfrac{8}{8}\quad \myfrac{88}{88}\par
\myfrac{9}{9}\quad \myfrac{99}{99}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Such fractions are ugly anyway.

What's `\str_case_e:nnTF`? The `_e` part means that the argument is subject to full expansion before being “stringified”, so `\tl_item:nn` is evaluated before the string is examined. The first argument to `\str_case_e:nnTF` is the string to be tested; the second argument should be in the form

```
{<str-1>}{<code for case-1>}
{<str-2>}{<code for case-2>}
...
{<str-n>}{<code for case-n>}
```

If there is a match, the corresponding code will be inserted, followed by the code in the third argument (`T`); no match results in the code of the fourth argument (`F`) to be inserted.

However, a very handy `expl3` convention is that `T` and `F` arguments are “special”, so we actually have a full quartet of functions, namely

```
\str_case_e:nn    \str_case_e:nnF    \str_case_e:nnT    \str_case_e:nnTF
```

and the most useful ones are the first two

Comment: I think this answer is more understandable, if I only had a better understanding for this syntax.  Upvoted and will play around with it.

Comment: @dedded I added a brief description of the case switch function.